# Practice of requesting dependency in calling when programming interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

When creating an interface having methods that are expected to be called in a specific order, is such dependency good practice, or should more patterns and practices be applied to "fix" it or make the situation better?

It's important users of some interfaces call methods in a specific order.

There are likely many various examples. This is the one that came to mind first:

A data source interface of which the author envisions the init method to always be called first by any caller (i.e to connect to the data source or look up preliminary meta info, etc), before any other of the operation methods are called.

```
interface DataAccess {

    // Note to callers: this init must be called first and only once.
    void InitSelf(); 

    // operation: get the record having the given id
    T Op_GetDataValue<T>(int id); 
    // operation: get a cound
    int Op_GetCountOfData(); 
    // operation: persist something to the data store        
    void Op_Persist(object o);         
    //etc.
}
```

However the caller may choose not to call the initialization method first.

In general I'm wondering if there are better ways for this situation.

Comment: Surely you would do all of that initialization on the constructor to ensure the object was set up before you interact with it?

Comment: @BeRecursive: Although I would normally answer Yes, but not necessarily considering the comment link here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361741/4361784#4361784 Interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused.  Implementors are not necessarily callers or users of the interface.  In your example, implementors can assume that InitSelf is called before anything else, but aren't responsible for making that happen.

I think naming something InitXXX is a good indication that that is the case.

For more odd dependencies (not Init, which is very common), it would probably be better to not have the dependency.

Sometimes, it's not possible, and if you decide that it's not overkill to try to fix it, then a common thing is to separate into multiple interfaces that you get access to as you call early ones.

A common example is a database interface.  You call connect, it returns a connection.  You call createStatement on the connection, it returns a statement.  You call setParam on the statement, you call runStatement on the statement, then you get a result, etc.

Comment: I was in the middle of updating the question with caller info while you were writing - take another peek and let me know if it's conceptually more clear now. Thx.

Comment: Interesting. The concept of incrementally providing one interface from another is likely the best way to provide resolution for such scenarios. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the other methods throw an exception if the object is uninitialized, or you could go for a more strict API.  It would be more complicated to implement, but for example, InitSelf() could return an interface containing the data operations:

```
interface DataAccess {
    DataOperations InitSelf();
}

interface DataOperations {
    T Op_GetDataValue<T>(int id);

    ...
}
```

This would sort of require the consumer to initialize before performing operations, though there would  be ways to circumvent that.

Comment: This is interesting. In the past I have implemented methods to throw exception if initialization has not yet occurred; however I haven't broken up the interface as your example shows. I like this example.

Answer (score 0):

Any initialization should be done in the constructor. Clients of the `DataAccess` interface should not have to worry about the construction details.

Comment: While this often seems the most logical, it also can lead to constructors that do too much.  http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/

Comment: @Matt: Initialize methods are still conceptually part of the "constructor", even if they aren't technically. You don't really fix anything that way. Ironically the page you link to even states as much: "watch out for initialize methods".

Comment: Good point.  I suppose use of Spring has had a bit of an effect on my mindset since it allows setting an automatically invoked initialization method.